# Ajax modal keeps disappearing

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Here I have HTML, PHP and Jquery code with where I can edit all my record using the modal, the problem is that it keeps disappearing after I click on my update button, the modal only shows for about half a second. Can you help me? I'm actually new and just learning Jquery

this is the front view

```
<?php
    include 'php/header.php';
    require_once 'php/connect.php';
?>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#input").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#body tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>


<style>

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;

}

td {
    text-align: center;
}

.edit {
    background-color: blue;
    font-family: algerian;
    color: lime;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.edit:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
}

.delete {
    color: white;
    background: black;
    font-family: algerian;

}


.delete:hover {
    color: black;
    background: yellow;

}
</style>

<h1 style=" font-family: algerian; color: lime" align="center">Assets</h1>
    <div class="filter">


<input style="height: 23px; float: right;"  id="input" type="text" placeholder="Search.." autocomplete="off"></div>
<br>
<br>
<table align="center">
<tr>

<a onclick="" href=""></a>

<thead>
    <th>Asset Num</th>
    <th>FA num</th>
    <th>Employee</th>
    <th>Team</th>
    <th>Contractor</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Disposed</th>
    <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
</thead>

    <tbody id="body">


<?php


$sql = " SELECT * FROM assets 
        LEFT JOIN team 
        ON assets.team_id = team.team_id
        LEFT JOIN contractor
        ON assets.contractor_id = contractor.contractor_id
        LEFT JOIN employee
        ON assets.employee_id =  employee.employee_id 
        LEFT JOIN item_status
        ON assets.status_id = item_status.status_id
        LEFT JOIN category
        ON assets.category_id = category.category_id
        ORDER BY category ";




    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


 if ($result->num_rows> 0) {




    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {


        if (empty($row["disposal_status_id"])) {
            $row["disposal_status_id"] = "NO"; }
            else {
               $row["disposal_status_id"] = "YES";
            }


        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>". $row["asset_num"] ."</td>" ;
        echo "<td>". $row["fa_num"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row["first_name"]. " " .$row["last_name"]. "</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row["team"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row["F_name"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row["item_status"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row["category"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row["disposal_status_id"] ."</td>";
        echo "<td><form method='POST' id='form'><button name='edit' class='edit' value=". $row['assets_id'] . " >Update</button></form>";
        echo "<td><a class='delete' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')\" 
                                href='php/delete_asset.php?id=".$row['assets_id']."'>Delete</a>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }
} 

    else {
        echo "<p style='font-family: algerian; font-size: 30px; margin-left: 45%; color: yellow ' >No Record</p>";
    }

?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

and this is the modal view

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".edit").click(function(){
            $("#modal").css('display', 'block');
        });
    });


</script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#cancel").click(function(){
            $("#modal").css("display", "none");
        });
    });
</script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#form").submit(function() {
                var edit = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {edit:edit},
                });

            });
        });
</script>





<?php
    include 'php/connect.php';


    $id = $_POST['edit'];






   $d = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT * FROM assets 
    LEFT JOIN employee 
    ON assets.employee_id = employee.employee_id
    LEFT JOIN team 
    ON assets.team_id = team.team_id
    LEFT JOIN contractor
    ON assets.contractor_id = contractor.contractor_id 
    LEFT JOIN item_status
    ON assets.status_id = item_status.status_id
    LEFT JOIN category
    ON assets.category_id = category.category_id
    LEFT JOIN disposal_status
    ON assets.disposal_status_id = disposal_status.disposal_status_id
    WHERE assets_id = '$id'");
   $check = mysqli_fetch_array($d);


function load_employee()

    {     
        include 'php/connect.php';
        $output = '';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY first_name";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $output .=  "<option value='" . $row['employee_id'] ."'>"
             . $row['first_name'] . " " 
             . $row['last_name'] . " </option>";
        }
        return $output;
    }

?>








<div id="modal">

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#employee').change(function(){
            var employee_id = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:"php/get_employee_team.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {employee_id:employee_id},
                    dataType:"text",
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        $('#team').html(data);
                    }

                });
            });
        });


</script>




<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../mystyle.css">

<style>

    #modal {

    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }

</style>

<form method="POST" action="php/update_assets.php" >  
<table align="center">
<th colspan="4" >Update Asset # <?php echo $check['assets_id']; ?></th>
<tr></tr>
<input style="display: none" type="text" name="assets_id" value="<?php echo $check['assets_id'] ?>">
<td>Asset Num:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="asset_num" value="<?php echo $check['asset_num'] ?>" autocomplete="off" required></td>
<td>Unit Condition:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="condition" value="<?php echo $check['condition'] ?>"  autocomplete="off" ></td>
<tr></tr>
<td>FA Num:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fa_num" value="<?php echo $check['fa_num'] ?>"  autocomplete="off" required></td>
<td>Audit Date:</td>
<td><input type="date" name="audit" value="<?php echo $check['audit_date'] ?>"  autocomplete="off"></td>
<tr></tr>
<tr>
<td>Employee:</td>
<td>
    <select id="employee" name="employee" >
        <?php
       echo "<option value='" . $check['employee_id'] ."'>"
           . $check['first_name'] . " " 
           . $check['last_name'] . " </option>";
           ?>
        <option><?php echo load_employee(); ?></option>
      </select>

</select></td>
<td>Location:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="location" value="<?php echo $check['location'] ?>"  autocomplete="off"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Team:</td>
<td>
    <select style="color: black" id="team" name="team" readonly>
        <option  value= "<?php echo $check['team_id'] ?>" ><?php echo $check['team'] ?></option>
    </select>       
</td>
<td>Insurance Date:</td>
<td><input type="date" name="insurance" value="<?php echo $check['audit_date'] ?>"></td>
</tr>
<td>Contractor:</td>
<td><select name="contractor">
  <?php
       echo "<option value='" . $check['contractor_id'] ."'>"
           . $check['F_name'] . " " 
           . $check['L_name'] . " </option>";
           ?>   
        <option>


    <?php

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM contractor" ;
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['contractor_id'] ."'>"
             . $row['F_name'] . " "
             . $row['L_name'] . "   </option>";
        }

        ?>

        </option>
    </select> </td>
<td>Comments:</td>
<td><input style="overflow: scroll;" type="text" name="comments" value="<?php echo $check['comments'] ?>" autocomplete="off"></td>

<tr></tr>
<td>Status:</td>
<td><select name="status">

    <?php
       echo "<option value='" . $check['status_id'] ."'>"
           . $check['item_status'] . "  </option>";
           ?>   
        <option>

            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM item_status " ;
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['status_id'] ."'>"
            . $row['item_status'] .  " </option>";
        }

        ?>
        </option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2"> <br></td>


<tr></tr>
<td>Asset Category:</td>
<td>
    <select name="category">
        <?php
       echo "<option value='" . $check['category_id'] ."'>"
           . $check['category'] . "  </option>";
           ?> 

        <option>

    <?php

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM category" ;
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['category_id'] ."'>"
             . $row['category'] . " </option>";
        }

        ?>

        </option>
    </select> 
</td>
<td colspan="2"> <br></td>
<tr></tr>
<td>Description:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo $check['description'] ?>" autocomplete="off">
<td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; color: blue; font-family: algerian" >DISPOSAL DETAILS</td>

<tr></tr>
<td>Serial Number:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="serial" value="<?php echo $check['serial_num'] ?>" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td>Disposal Location</td>
<td><input type="text" name="disposal_loc" value="<?php echo $check['disposal_location'] ?>" autocomplete="off"></td>
<tr></tr>
<td>Date Aquired:</td>
<td><input type="date" name="acquired" value="<?php echo $check['date_get'] ?>" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td>Date Disposed</td>
<td><input type="date" name="disposal_date"  value="<?php echo $check['disposal_date'] ?>" autocomplete="off"></td>
<tr></tr>
<td>Purchase Price:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="price"  value="<?php echo $check['purchase_price'] ?>" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td>Disposed Status</td>
<td>
    <select  id="dept" name="disposal_status">
        <?php


           if ($check['disposal_status_id'] == 0) {
              echo "<option  value='". $checl['disposal_status_id'] ."' >";
              echo "NOT YET";
              echo "</option>";
           }
           ?> 
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM disposal_status " ;
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['disposal_status_id'] ."'>"
            . $row['status'] .  " </option>";
        }

        ?>
    </select>
</td>
<tr></tr>
<br>

<td  style="text-align: center;" colspan="4"><button type="submit" name="btn" class="submit" >Submit</button>
<p class="submit" id="cancel">Cancel</p></form>

        </td>

</table>

</div>
```

I try to send the data in the same page and try to change the CSS code when I click on the Update button, sending the id and fetching the data required using ajax Jquery, Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? Please separate the modal view and current view above so that we determine what is the modal view.

Comment: done good sir, and no, I don't use bootstrap

Comment: You can put your scripts in a single `$(document).ready(function())` and also declare scripts on every end of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `preventDefault()` function because the nature of submiting form is to refresh the page that's also the reason why the modal is appearing just a couple of seconds only or sometimes it is not appearing.

Please try these line of code.

```
$("#form").on("submit",function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var edit = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {edit:edit},
            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: OK, this works, but it only works on the first one in the table, the other ones just keep disappearing again when I click update.

Comment: Still need help, I've done the above mention butit only works in the first list of the table

Comment: it is because of this <form method="POST" action="php/update_assets.php" >  you need to add some ajax active in here too.

Comment: Hmmmm, I'll try